# How I can Combine two arrays in view and insert into database - Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hellow guys, Im a new member in this platform...

Im using codeigniter framework and I have two different arrays in my view. The first array contains the data from the form input called customerData,

```
customerData = {    customerid : customerid,
                    customername : customername,
                    address : address,
                    city : city,
                    phone : phone
                };
```

and the second one is the array containing the data in dynamically generated html table called tableData.

How I can combine these two arrays and send them to different tables using Ajax Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of are data of second table?

Javascript allows you merge two array:

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

Comment: My idea is to create a page for Invoice Sales on which Customer's information are fed into the form inputs as specified in the array above... The second array should contain the data of all the items purchased which were dynamically added in a HTML table. Then both data from the form inputs and html table should be saved into my database